# 4store install: perl(Net::HTTP) is needed by 4store-v1.1.2-1.x86_64

Tags: perl, 4store

I just followed the instruction at http://4store.org/trac/wiki/Download:

```
rpm -Uvh http://4store.org/download/linux/centos5/4store-v1.1.2-1.x86_64.rpm http://4store.org/download/linux/centos5/rasqal-0.9.24-1.x86_64.rpm http://4store.org/download/linux/centos5/raptor2-2.0.0-0.x86_64.rpm http://4store.org/download/linux/centos5/mpfr-2.4.1-1.x86_64.rpm http://4store.org/download/linux/centos5/gmp-4.3.1-5.x86_64.rpm
```

I got errors when installing 4store on CentOS 5.6:

```
perl(Net::HTTP) is needed by 4store-v1.1.2-1.x86_64
perl(URI::Escape) is needed by 4store-v1.1.2-1.x86_64
```

But I have already installed those modules:

```
cpan Net::HTTP
cpan URI::Escape
```

And I tested it with:

```
perl -MNet::HTTP -e ';'
```

But I still got those errors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

CPAN clients do not register modules in the RPM database, so that does not help to satisfy dependencies.

`perl-Net-HTTP` and `perl-URI-Escape` are not officially packaged for CentOS 5.6: http://vault.centos.org/5.6/os/x86_64/CentOS/

- Find a 3rd party repo that offers them.
- Try to force the installation with `--nodeps`.
- You could also bribe [Dave Cross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/dave-cross) to backport his maintained packages from CentOS 6: http://rpm.mag-sol.com/Centos/6/x86_64/
- Learn packaging and build them yourself.